# Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to release my Android application with Gradle.

app build Grade::

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 24

    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }    
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: set `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"`

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya   still not working :(

Comment: add `minifyEnabled false` instead of  `true`

Comment: but i want  minifyEnabled true , Because i want protect my app from Reverse Engineering

Comment: can any one help me?? :(